# SQL Query in Sequelize getter method

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using the Postgres extension 'earthdistance' for lat/long distance calculation.

I'm also using Sequelize to access the database and I want to define a getter
method for calculation and sorting by distance from a set of coordinates.

The following query works fine:

```
SELECT name, 
       earth_distance(ll_to_earth( 51.5241182, -0.0758046 ), 
       ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)) as distance_from_current_location 
FROM "Branches" 
ORDER BY distance_from_current_location ASC;
```

And I can use it using sequelize.query(), but I want to keep all the model queries part of the model.

How can I specify WHERE conditions from inside a getter method in the model definition?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to do the same thing in postgres using sequelize. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably to wrap the query in a stored procedure and pass in the arguments you want to use in the where clause. As stored procedures are compiled, this will perform better than a Dynamic SQL where you generate the WHERE clause on the fly.

Add whatever parameters and types to your stored proc as you need, and the result will look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetEarthDistance (v_Foo bigint) RETURNS type AS $$
DECLARE 
   v_Name varchar(256);
BEGIN
SELECT name INTO v_Name, 
   earth_distance(ll_to_earth( 51.5241182, -0.0758046 ), 
   ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)) as distance_from_current_location 
FROM Branches 
WHERE somecol > v_foo
ORDER BY distance_from_current_location ASC;

RETURN v_Name; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```